# Text Input field after selection of radio button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a form where the text field appears when the user selects the 'Yes' radio button and the text field will not appear when the user selects 'No'. I got this code from the internet.
However, it cannot work as I am using Laravel and do not know how to convert the php code.

This is the code:

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
            var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
            dvPassport.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span>Do you have Passport?</span>
    <label for="chkYes">
        <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
        Yes
    </label>
    <label for="chkNo">
        <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
        No
    </label>
    <hr />
    <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
        Passport Number:
        <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, I don't find any issue here.

Comment: Your code seems to work properly, is there any error that you are seeing in your browser's console?

Comment: Well Larvel is a `PHP` framework so you can use `JavaScript` in `PHP` files . And what you're asking is done by client side languages like `JavaScript`.  `PHP` is a server side language which wont help you in your case.

Comment: I want to change this into Laravel - 

<span>Do you have Passport?</span>
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    No
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
</div>

Comment: Again `larvel` is `PHP` not another language what you're asking is us to write the exact `JavaScript` code for your form.  You already have the answer just change the `JavaScript` part match yours. It's just simple `JavaScript`ing.

Answer (score 3):

To show/hide input box on click of the radio button, you need to first create the radio buttons with the `same name` but `different value`.

Create a `click` event and check if the value is `yes` or `no`.

Show/Hide the `text` box accordingly.

```js
$('input[name="choose"]').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.value === 'yes') {
    $('#optional').show();
  } else {
    $('#optional').hide();
  }
})

$('#optional').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="choose" value='yes'>Yes
<input type="radio" name="choose" value='no'>No
<input type="text" id="optional">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running well.
You just need some changes in html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
        var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
        dvPassport.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
<span>Do you have Passport?</span>
<label for="chkYes">

    // i just set default value to you have passport

    <input type="radio" id="chkYes" checked name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    No
</label>
<hr />

//i just make div visible with passport number 

<div id="dvPassport">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: let me know if it does not work for you.... if worked please accept as correct answer

Comment: Yes.

I want to be able to change this code to put in the 'blade.php' file.

</script>
<span>Do you have Passport?</span>
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    No
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
</div>

Comment: you can save it with `file_name.blade.php` and call with `View::('file_name'); ` this must work... i tested in laravel 5.4 and working for me

Comment: View::('file_name'); in 'web.php' ?

Comment: `Route::get('/file-test-for-toggle',function(){ return View('file_name')});` file-test-for-toggle is url code should be written in `/app/http/routes.php`and you need to save your file in `/resources/views/` folder

Comment: It can work now but I need to add the data from the radio button and the text field into the database?

Comment: you need to create form and submit

Comment: I cannot do this multiple times because I need to add an another radio button option with the optional text field.
I want to have 2 sets of radio buttons and text fields